# /dev/console dynamic redirection

Tags: linux, console, embedded

Is it possible to dynamically redirect all data sent to `/dev/console` into something else (for example - to `/dev/null`, `/dev/tty9` or even `/dev/null`)?

Of course, it can be done *statically* via `console=XXX` kernel boot parameter (or standard pipe redirection in case of a single program). The problem is that I need to do it dynamically (and for all programs that do output), based on data that comes from an external device.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not common for programs to *directly* write to `/dev/console`, usually `printk()` or `syslogd` are the source. Permissions are (usually) 600 root:root.

Comment: Yes, it's `/sbin/init`, services and a few other programs. I just want to find a solution that does not require to modify start-up scripts (or redirect output in multiple places). Something simple and robust.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few options I can think of, their effectiveness depends on how things get on to "the console".

For kernel-sourced messages the simplest is to use `dmesg -n 1` to disable (practically all) console messages, and use syslogd/klogd to extract and either log them or forward them. All kernel messages still get logged and are accessible via `/proc/kmsg` (or `sys_syslog()`) regardless of the console log level. A variation on this is to boot your kernel with `quiet` which suppresses `printk()` output, and rely only on syslogd/klogd to process kernel messages.

A more adventurous and comprehensive option is to use a *console module*, these are more commonly used in VM guests so that the VM host can access guest consoles directly. There are [two types](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/console/console.txt), the *system driver* (e.g. "VGA" on an x86 PC, the kernel "console=" option); and the *modular driver* which can be loaded and unloaded as needed, and may take over the system driver. One possibly useful driver is [netconsole](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/netconsole.txt), while it's readily loadable and un-loadable (it can be used as both a system and modular driver) there are two downsides:

- it doesn't `take_over_console()` so everything still goes to the original console
- it only logs via ethernet (loopback is not supported)

You may be able to do something useful with the "dummy" console, and one of the options above. `netcat` or `socat` make good "clients" for a netconsole:

```
modprobe netconsole "netconsole=55514@10.0.2.15/eth0,6667@10.1.2.3/ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
socat UDP4-LISTEN:55514 -
```

If you're more interested in capturing console output from individual system services, then I don't think there's a simple way without script modifications.

Not-simple (and possibly not nice) ways of doing this include using LD_PRELOAD to <strike>hijack</strike> redirect functions that generate output, or to add some `_init` code to amend default file descriptors. Or worse: attaching with a debugger and [manipulating the open file descriptors](http://blog.tridgell.net/?p=4). `/etc/ld.so.preload` would be a simple (if hackish and slightly nasty) way of implementing the first option.

If I wanted to monitor console output for daemons, I'd probably amend the startup scripts to run them in `screen` sessions, perhaps [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534386/how-can-i-script-gnu-screen-to-start-with-a-program-running-inside-of-it-so-that).