# Redirect console to a serial port

Tags: linux, debian, console, serial-port, serial-console

I have a serial port `/dev/ttyS2` that is connected to a supervisor. Normally, I use this line to send commands back and forth between CPU and supervisor.

However, under some settings, I want to just redirect the entire console to this port.

I can achieve this via a reboot and updating the uBoot kernel variable to direct `console=ttyS2,115200`. But is there a way to achieve this without a reboot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could launch getty once you've booted to get a serial connection to your system. Note that this will not give you the default outputs typically seen with your console (Kernel Panics and other verbosities typically seen in console but not in normal terminals). But if you are just looking to get a login via serial after boot this should work.

```
/sbin/agetty -L 115200 ttyS2 vt100
```

That should connect to `/dev/ttyS2` at `115200` baud and emulate a `vt100` terminal.

Comment: Just a note, you need to run this as root (sudo) for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, as far as I know. The `netconsole` modules does something similar, but for network devices. You may want to write a kernel module based on it. Further references:

- [/dev/console dynamic redirection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97330/dev-console-dynamic-redirection)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829746/how-to-switch-linux-kernel-console-after-boot-process